# Erasing last line from multiline textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I am writing a small winform program which has a multiline textbox and a button "Clear". Every string that I append to this textbox, always ends with "\r\n".

```
textBoxScriptSteps.AppendText(ClickedButton + "\r\n");
```

I want to erase only the last line on every click of clear button.

Searched in the google but couldn't find any solution.
Any help in this please.

Comment: Do you have any attempt at this so far? My guess is you could find the last occurrence of "\r\n" in the string `textBoxScriptSteps.Text` and go from there. Just a general idea for you.

Comment: Easiest way (I think) is to take the contents, split them based upon your newline characters into an array / list and then re-output the list back simply without the last element... But without showing us what you tried, I'm afraid you won't get any concrete solutions...

Comment: Yes i tried this, but it doesn't do anything.
textBoxScriptSteps.Text.Remove(textBoxScriptSteps.Text.LastIndexOf("\r\n"));

Comment: `string[] textlines = textBoxScriptSteps.Lines; textlines = textlines.Where(x => x != textlines[textlines.Count].ToArray(); textBoxScriptSteps.Lines = textlines;` You mean something like that? Don't forget to add: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Strings are immutable. If you just did `.Remove` without actually assigning the returned value back to `textBoxScriptSteps.Text`, of course it doesn't do anything. It's possible that worked (assuming the string doesn't end with `\r\n`) but just didn't do anything with the correct string :)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

HTML Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(TextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
}
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29118aad-dfec-4453-a653-18fa51d63252/how-to-clear-the-last-line-in-multiline-textbox?forum=vblanguage

Answer (score 4):

I found an simpler way:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(TextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(TextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
TextBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.
Keep a `List<string>`.  Everytime you click add, add the element to the list.
Everytime you click clear remove an element from the end.

Have an UpdateText method that sets the text in the textbox.  Call UpdateText at the end of your methods for adding and clearing.

Separate the data from the display.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```
public String RemoveLastLine(String myStr)
{
    String result = "";
    if (myStr.Length > 2)
    {
        // Ignore very last new-line character.
        String temporary = myStr.Substring(0, myStr.Length - 2);

        // Get the position of the last new-line character.
        int lastNewLine = temporary.LastIndexOf("\r\n");

        // If we have at least two elements separated by a new-line character.
        if (lastNewLine != -1)
        {
            // Cut the string (starting from 0, ending at the last new-line character).
            result = myStr.Substring(0, lastNewLine);
        }
    }
    return (result);
}
```

You can use this function to get your text without the last line.
For example, calling `RemoveLastLine();` with `"Hello\r\nWorld\r\n"` will give you `"Hello\r\n"`.
So you can do `textBoxScriptSteps.Text = RemoveLastLine(textBoxScriptSteps.Text);` every time the button is pressed.

---

*The same function more compact:*

```
public String RemoveLastLine(String myStr) {
    if (myStr.Length > 2) {
        int lastNewLine;
        if ((lastNewLine = myStr.Substring(0, myStr.Length - 2).LastIndexOf("\r\n")) != -1)
            return (myStr.Substring(0, lastNewLine));
    }
    return ("");
}
```